# The correct icon size for Android Adaptive Icons

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-8.0-oreo

What are the image dimensions for a Android Adaptive Icon in Android O for the size xxxhdpi? You now have a foreground layer image and a background layer image.

Is the solution to simply use two images of 192x192 pixels?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/adaptive-icons.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/adaptive-icons.html):

> Both layers must be sized at 108 x 108 dp.

Adaptive icons support SVG (VectorDrawable). So you can just provide two SVG of dimensions 108 x 108 dp for foreground and background layers.

If you want to use PNG images, you have to calculate the dimensions for other densities.

So for xxxhdpi: 108 * 4 => 432 x 432 pixels.

You can use any [dp/px calculator](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/) to calculate for other densities.

Comment: Thank you for your help Bob! This works brilliantly.

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss, I used a shape drawable for my background, and a vector for the foreground. Both sized at 108x108dp. The issue is that this somehow scales wrong and either shrinks the background or stretches the foreground. I end up with no padding even though the foreground svg clearly leaves room in the viewport. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the perhaps obvious question, but how do you create an SVG of 108x108 dp? We have an SVG logo which obviously scales well in all sizes, but how do I know if it's 108x108dp or less/more? The viewbox is "0 0 300 300". Does that mean 300x300dp?

Comment: when you are importing svg to android studio you will be asked to enter size by default it will be 24X24  , you have to click on override checkbox and enter size 108X108

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer Android seems to automatically scale up the foreground layer. You can make play on the scale thought, using the difference between the width/height of the layer and the viewportWidth/viewportHeight. Let's say, if you want a foreground layer 2x smaller, you need to use a 216x216 viewport for example. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Edouard Brèthes - Thank you - do you know how I then center the rescaled vector afterwards? Mine wen't to one side when I tried this, and is now outside the edge of the viewport of the adaptive icon.

Comment: @nsandersen my guess is that your original SVG is hooked to (0,0) position rather than be centered. I'd suggest you to edit the SVG to solve that : place it in a bigger canvas with enough margin to be centered, and export it like that. Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, thanks. I also found that it is possible to use translateX and translateY attributes in a group tag enclosing the vector path tag. But your option may allow me to reuse my vector rather than "having different sizes of it" (doh!).

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio itself has a generator which can help you create the icons you need.

To do this right click on the res folder -> new -> Image Asset. Then just follow the Wizard.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

Comment: I've downloaded Android Studio for OS X just because of this answer, but couldn't find an menu option for New -> Image Asset anywhere. I don't know if it has been removed or if you need to download additional tools, but it doesn't seem to be present anymore.

Comment: @AdamReis - right click in the project view > new > image asset

Comment: Thank you for this tip! This gets me most of the way there, but how do I upload my own SVG for the foreground?